# Reading a text file in unicode from a URL?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to use urllib and urllib2 to read from a text file that has french characters in it, like "é", "à", and so on.

```
def load(url):
     from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

     req = Request(url)

     f = urlopen(req)
     f.readline()

     for line in f:
          line = line.split('\t')
          word = line[0].encode('utf-8')
```

I have a feeling that the read() method returns me a byte string, so I use encode('utf-8') to get the unicode value, but this gives me the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're reading bytes from the file. What you must do is *decode*, not *encode*, the byte string into Unicode. It's *already* encoded, you see. If it wasn't, you wouldn't need to do anything with it.

```
word = unicode(line[0], "utf8")
```

You have to specify the encoding *used in the file.* If it's not `utf8`, another good suspect might be `latin1`. Or, you know, since it's a Web document, you could fish the document's encoding out of the headers and/or its content, but that's a little beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

put below code at the top.

```
# coding: utf-8
```

actually supporting unicode is not easy for python.
also recommand this article .

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263

http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/100ec019d3a2a1a9